# function referring to object doesn't remove it from stage

Tags: javascript, oop, reflection, pixi.js

the function doesn't remove the object:

```
const app = new PIXI.Application({
  resizeTo: window
});

current_sprite = new PIXI.Sprite.from(`backgammon/dices/Alea_${user.cubes[index][0]}.png`);

current_sprite.delete = () => {
  console.log("current_sprite:");
  console.log(current_sprite);
  app.stage.removeChild(current_sprite);
}
```

meanwhile it does recognize the object. My main question is if this syntax is correct in javascript? can I refer in a block to the object trying to define a property of his? or should I use the e.target syntax?

definition of the array:
`other_cubes[index] = [current_sprite, next_sprite];`

and
next_sprite
is identical to current.
the call is:
`other_cubes[current.Inex_ToCube2][0].delete();`
and the index is 5 - which makes sense;
the array is built correctly becuase the printed output makes sense.

Comment: please add current_sprite object value and console.log(app.stage) to see if it is undefined

Comment: it's not, but I can attach a few more lines of code.

Comment: I did, thank you, I appreciate the fact you're trying to help, I hope that the new lines and the clarification at the bottom help

Comment: How do you execute the function? did you call it somewhere?

Comment: the call is most likely to be correct - because I get an object in my console that fits the value and type of the wanted object.